# Mockito issue w.r.t spring boot upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, upgrade, junit4, powermockito

We are facing an issue with Mockito post spring boot version upgrade

Following is the configuration

- Mockito-all : 1.10.19
- PowerMockito : 1.6.2
- SpringBootVersion : 2.6.3
- Junit : 4.12
- Hamcrest-all : 1.3

Reported exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.example.Sample(sample.java:109)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
```

I tried changing versions of mockito from `1.1` to `1.10.19` and even with powermockito as well but it doesnt help. error keeps coming.

Comment: Remove `mockito-all`, `junit` and `hamcrest` dependencies, add `spring-boot-starter-test` and fix the compilation issues due to changes in mockito (it pulls in mockito 4+).